# Where should omniauth.rb be located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, omniauth

**The context :**

I have a rails engine (gem) that uses omniauth inside it to authenticate the users for the entire engine. Then, that engine is used by a regular rails application.

I am using Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.2.

**The question :**

In my application that uses my engine (which in turn uses omniauth), where should the `omniauth.rb` file be located?

- In the engine's `initializers` folder?
- In the regular application `initializers` folder?
- In some kind of engine folder in my regular application, such as `initializers/engine_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should place it in:

```
lib/oauth/omniauth.rb
```

Comment: In my rails engine (gem), in the `lib` folder, same place as `engine_name.rb` (assuming my engine is called `engine_name`) ?

Comment: ah, you want to make a gem? then put it to lib/oauth/omniauth.rb and include it.